# How can we balance off the imbalance generated by the data loader for a binary classification problem

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I have created a synthesized dataset and the corresponding data loader for a binary classification problem using Pytorch. The zero class happens almost 20% and the other one 80%. When I train my model it only predicts the 80% ones which makes sense because it has seen the one with label one 80% of the time.

**How can I handle this imbalance after getting the data from the data loader?**

**Is BCELoss capable of understanding this situation?**

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

class MyDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_size=50000):
        self.data_size = data_size

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return self.data_size

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        data, label (label=0 (20%) or label=1 (80%)) = my_function()
        return data, label

dataset = MyDataset()
# Assume a default batch size of 1
batch_size = 1000
dl = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size)

# network

loss_fn = torch.nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-6)

losses = []
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    print(f"EPOCH: {epoch}")
       for data, label in tqdm(dl, total=len(dl)):
            data= data.to(DEVICE).float()
            label = label.to(DEVICE).float()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            preds = model(data)
            prob = torch.sigmoid(preds)
            loss = loss_fn(prob, label)
            loss.backward()
            losses.append(loss.detach().cpu().numpy())
            optimizer.step()
            # break
```

**Question:**

I have read about [the weight argument](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCELoss.html#torch.nn.BCELoss) for BCELoss but I am not sure if I can use it here or not. To me, it does not handle imbalance in the data. Note that I cannot manipulate my dataset since in practice the percentage is inherit it the data and we cannot change it from source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "after getting the data from the data loader" but I'll suggest anyway that you could oversample the minority class by using a `WeightedRandomSampler`. This will make sure that the dataloader always returns the same amount of samples for each class. So there will be a 50/50 chance that it returns a sample of class 1 and 0. Here is how to do it:

```py
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, WeightedRandomSampler

class MyDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_size=50000):
        self.data_size = data_size

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return self.data_size

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        data, label (label=0 (20%) or label=1 (80%)) = my_function()
        return data, label

dataset = MyDataset()
# Assume a default batch size of 1
batch_size = 1000

class_weights = [1/20, 1/80] # inverse relative amount of samples per class
sample_weights = [0] * len(dataset)

for idx, (data, label) in enumerate(dataset):
    sample_weights[idx] = class_weights[label]

sampler = WeightedRandomSampler(sample_weights, num_samples=len(sample_weights), replacement=True)
dl = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=sampler)

# continue with your code...
```

And using a weighted loss can also improve the accuracy. You can simply do something like this:

```py
weights = [1/20, 1/80] # or [4, 1] or [1/2, 1/4] you can try whatever as long as the proportions match the class distribution in your dataset
loss_fn = nn.BCELoss(weights=weights)
```

You can use both of the methods. And of course the most effective method: augmentation. If it's possible for you to synthetically create more samples from your dataset the do that. An example for augmentation with images is to flip, rotate, crop the images to create slighty different ones. You could add that to your dataset class and have a 80% that the minority class is augmented.

Comment: **Question 1:** Should I replace the block you posted after my `dataset = MyDataset()` up to the losss, i.e., `loss_fn = torch.nn.BCELoss()` with not weight? I appreciate if you rearrange my code and embed your suggested solution. **Question 2** what do you mean by "You can simply do something like this" `loss_fn = nn.BCELoss(weights=weights)`, what is `weights`? You do not calculate it in your code? **Question 3** Is there any way to avoid looping through dataset since when data is large this will take time?

Comment: I updated my answer. To your third question: I think for the ``WeightedRandomSampler`` you have to specify a weight for each sample in your dataset and therefore have to iterate over the entire thing once

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you can use a weighted BCELoss accordingly (eg: 0.2 weight on class 1 and 0.8 weight on class 0). Otherwise, you can opt to use a `WeightedRandomSampler` for your dataloader in order to assign a higher probability of sampling class 0 and a lower probability of sampling class 1. Again, the probability of sampling should also be done accordingly. These two methods can be generalized to any arbitrary number of classes `c`.

An example of using the `WeightedRandomSampler`:

```
weights = [0.8, 0.2]
targets = dataset.targets  # Where "dataset" is type <class 'torchvision.datasets>
samples_weight = weights[targets]  # Will assign the 0th index value in "weights" to every 0 in "targets", and the 1st index value in "weights" to every 1 in "targets"
w_sampler = WeightedRandomSampler(samples_weight, len(samples_weight))
weighted_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=BS, sampler=w_sampler)
```

Comment: can you please provide an answer in code because following your suggestion is not straight forward.